# How i can implement 2 arrays in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

`Hello!
I have a tableview and 2 arrays.
[image]
When I switch between tabs the tableview reloads. In the first tab, I click on favorites, change the color and add the data to another array. When switching to the second tab, the color does not change. how can i implement this?

MyCell

```
protocol CellSubclassDelegate: class {
   func gestureTapped(cell: StocksCell)
}

class StocksCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var logoImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tickerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var favouriteImageView: UIImageView!{ didSet {
    let panGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapToAddFavourite))
    favouriteImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    favouriteImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var companyNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var deltaLabel: UILabel!

var selectedCell = false
weak var delegate: CellSubclassDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

@objc private func tapToAddFavourite(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard recognizer.state == .ended else { return }
    if selectedCell{
        favouriteImageView.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        selectedCell = false
    }else{
        favouriteImageView.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
        selectedCell = true
    }
    self.delegate?.gestureTapped(cell: self)
}
}
```

MyController

```
class StocksViewController: UIViewController, CellSubclassDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var stocksLabel: UILabel! { didSet {
    let tapGestureStocks = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapToStocks))
    stocksLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureStocks)
    stocksLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var favouriteLabel: UILabel!{ didSet {
    let tapGestureFavourite = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapToFavourite))
    favouriteLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureFavourite)
    favouriteLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

fileprivate var stocksData = [StocksModel(n: "VNDX", f: "Vandex, LLC", t: "4 764,6 ₽", tt: "+55 ₽ (1,15%)"), StocksModel(n: "DDD", f: "Dandex, LLC", t: "1 764,6 ₽", tt: "+155 ₽ (1,15%)")]

var favouriteData = [StocksModel]()

let privateIdentifire = "StocksCell"
var isStocksSelected = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

@objc private func tapToFavourite(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard recognizer.state == .ended else { return }
    favouriteLabel.alpha = 1
    favouriteLabel.font = favouriteLabel.font.withSize(28)
    stocksLabel.alpha = 0.65
    stocksLabel.font = stocksLabel.font.withSize(18)
    stocksLabel.textAlignment = .center
    isStocksSelected = false
    tableView.reloadData()
}
@objc private func tapToStocks(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard recognizer.state == .ended else { return }
    favouriteLabel.alpha = 0.65
    favouriteLabel.font = favouriteLabel.font.withSize(18)
    stocksLabel.alpha = 1
    stocksLabel.font = stocksLabel.font.withSize(28)
    stocksLabel.textAlignment = .left
    isStocksSelected = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

TABLEVIEW DATASOURCE

```
extension StocksViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let result = isStocksSelected ? stocksData.count : favouriteData.count
        return result
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: privateIdentifire, for: indexPath) as! StocksCell
    cell.delegate = self
    
    if isStocksSelected{
        cell.tickerLabel.text = stocksData[indexPath.row].name
        cell.companyNameLabel.text = stocksData[indexPath.row].fullname
        cell.priceLabel.text = stocksData[indexPath.row].ticker
        cell.deltaLabel.text = stocksData[indexPath.row].tq
    }else{
        cell.tickerLabel.text = favouriteData[indexPath.row].name
        cell.companyNameLabel.text = favouriteData[indexPath.row].fullname
        cell.priceLabel.text = favouriteData[indexPath.row].ticker
        cell.deltaLabel.text = favouriteData[indexPath.row].tq
    }
    return cell
}

func gestureTapped(cell: StocksCell) {
    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {return}
    if cell.selectedCell{
        let dataStock = stocksData[indexPath.row]
        favouriteData.append(dataStock)
    }else{
        favouriteData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }
}
}
```

TABLEVIEW DELEGATE

```
 extension StocksViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 68
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 16
 }
}
```

Comment: In `tableView(_:cellForRow:)` check if it's present in `favouriteData` and tint it if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Change the color here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: privateIdentifire, for: indexPath) as! StocksCell
    cell.delegate = self
    
    if isStocksSelected{
        favouriteImageView.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.tickerLabel.text = stocksData[indexPath.row].name
        cell.companyNameLabel.text = stocksData[indexPath.row].fullname
        cell.priceLabel.text = stocksData[indexPath.row].ticker
        cell.deltaLabel.text = stocksData[indexPath.row].tq
    }else{
        favouriteImageView.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
        cell.tickerLabel.text = favouriteData[indexPath.row].name
        cell.companyNameLabel.text = favouriteData[indexPath.row].fullname
        cell.priceLabel.text = favouriteData[indexPath.row].ticker
        cell.deltaLabel.text = favouriteData[indexPath.row].tq
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You can also do this in `willDisplayCell`, which will be called just before drawing.